# javascript and iframe not supported in browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari, cross-browser

I run a simple html file with an iframe and javascript working fine in IE Browser, but it is not working in other browsers like safari,firefox.

In safari the Iframe box is only displayed, but the content in that is not shown.

Please clarify why safari doesn't support it? what are the alternatives for iframe?

Comment: there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: Show us what you're doing. If possible try to make the smallest example page that you can that replicates the result and post it either directly in the question or host it somewhere like jsfiddle.net

Comment: FYI: The reason we're all asking to see your code is because iframe+javascript works on all browsers. But there are hundreds (thousands?) if small incompatibilities between browsers. To list them all will be like writing a novel.

Comment: This is my code.It is working fine in Ie,But in safari It just displays box and doesn't show anything.                        <html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" > function f() { document.write("you have clicked the button"); } </script> </head> <body> <iframe src="D:/15/fscript.html" width="600" height="400" > </iframe> </body> </html>

Comment: There is mistake in address i guess..

If you have that fscript.html in the same folder then dont give whole address.

<iframe src="fscript.html" width="600" height="400" > </iframe>

will fix.

Comment: Post some code.  Maybe create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<embed>` tag ,which behaves like iframe

Here is example

```
<!doctype html >
<html >
<head>
<title>embed  Tag </title>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>Example of embed tag in HTML5.</b></p>
<embed src="http://www.w3schools.com" height="300" width="300" />
</body>
</html>
```

While you can also use iframes on all browser

Here is example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Are you trying to do any different for iframe ?

Comment: Thank You.the embed tag is working fine,But is this supported in other browsers(Firefox,chrome,IE).In IE it doesn't show the content.It just shows the box with img icon.

Comment: <embed> tag was working on Chrome ,IE and Safari and for Firefox it was asking to download some plugin  to run the code

Comment: please update your IE or check address bar it might be showing some alert over there, cause I have checked in IE its working excellent here.